# javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint.name()Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource 
[ApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint.name()Ljava/lang/String;**

what is wrong about that?

I  use the

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.aaaedu.aaaspeak3</groupId>
<artifactId>aaaspeak3</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>aaaspeak3 Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>

    <javax.version>6.0</javax.version>
    <javax.servlet.version>1.2</javax.servlet.version>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    <org.aspectj.version>1.6.2</org.aspectj.version>
    <net.sf.ehcache.version>2.3.2</net.sf.ehcache.version>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.6.1</org.slf4j.version>
    <mysql.jdbc.version>5.1.15</mysql.jdbc.version>
    <org.hibernate.entitymanager.version>3.6.10.Final</org.hibernate.entitymanager.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <com.jolbox.bonecp.version>0.7.1.RELEASE</com.jolbox.bonecp.version>
    <org.codehaus.jackson.version>1.7.4</org.codehaus.jackson.version>
    <commons.pool.version>20030821.192746</commons.pool.version>
    <commons.dbcp.version>20030821.193421</commons.dbcp.version>
    <org.jfreechart.version>1.0.14</org.jfreechart.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype snapshot repository</name>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net2</id>
        <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss</id>
        <name>The "public-jboss" repository group provides a combined view all JBoss community project artifacts</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <id>bonecp-repo</id>
        <name>BoneCP Repository</name>
        <url>http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/maven</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>CodeHaus-Jackson</id>
        <name>Json CodeHaus Jackson</name>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/jackson/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

     <!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>${net.sf.ehcache.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BoneCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>${com.jolbox.bonecp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${com.jolbox.bonecp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${com.jolbox.bonecp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.pool.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>${org.jfreechart.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>aaaspeak3</finalName>
</build>
```

somebody tell me that it is Conflict between "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.jar" and others.how do I do that? thank you!

Comment: Without your full pom it's hard to say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dependency is for JPA 1:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

As you see UniqueConstraint in [JPA 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html) does not have `name` attribute, but in [JPA 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html#name%28%29) it is there. You do refer to "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.jar", which is  JPA 2.0 API provided by Hibernate. But your pom.xml does not include such a file. You can include that (or actually never version) by adding following to pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally you should remove dependency to JPA 1 API.